# Why does "su - -c" make this fail?

Tags: linux, bash

Why does this fail?

```
~$ su - -c "k=0; if ls | grep -q ^Desktop; then k=1; fi; if [ $k == 1 ]; then echo 1; fi"
Password: 
-bash: line 0: [: ==: unary operator expected
```

It works without the `su - -c` part.

**Update**

It was a simplified example, what I really wanted was

```
ssh -t $host 'su - -c "k=0; if yum check-updates | grep -q ^kernel-; then k=1; fi; yum -y update; if [ \$k == 1 ]; then reboot; fi"'
```

which now works thanks to the help I got here.

Comment: What's root's default shell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because your shell will do a variable expansion (because you're using double quotes), and very likely `k` expands to nothing since it's not set. Please consider instead:

```
su - -c "k=0; if ls | grep -q ^Desktop; then k=1; fi; if [ \$k == 1 ]; then echo 1; fi"
```

(with escaped dollar) or:

```
su - -c 'k=0; if ls | grep -q ^Desktop; then k=1; fi; if [ $k == 1 ]; then echo 1; fi'
```

with single quotes that prevent variable expansion.

---

And by the way, [it's very bad to parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)! it seems your problem is to determine whether a file or directory with name starting with `Desktop` exists. Using a little bit of heuristic, I guess you *really* mean whether there exists a *directory* the name of which is *exactly* Desktop. In this case:

```
if [[ -d Desktop ]]; then k=1; fi
```

will be much better. If not in Bash (or in Bash but want to avoid Bashisms):

```
if [ -d Desktop ]; then k=1; fi
```

Comment: For that matter, the variable `k` isn't needed at all. `if [ -d Desktop ]; then echo 1; fi`.

Comment: @chepner But who knows what the OP is really up to with this variable `k`!

Comment: I have now updated OP with what I actually wanted to do. I don't suppose it could have been done smarter? I tend to like `[ -d Desktop ] && k=1` if possible.

Comment: @JasmineLognnes So my heuristic was useless and my guess plain wrong. Whatever. At least you really were able to simplify your problem, and that made it easier to answer. Good luck.